# Who are these BSD Unix contributors?

Tags: history, bsd

I'm trying to piece together the names of the people who contributed to BSD Unix, according to the contents of the SCCS logs.  (This is the version control system used at the time.) A number of names appear [in a list](https://github.com/jonathangray/csrg-git-patches/blob/master/map) created by Jonathan Gray, but 72 are still missing.  To keep this process organized, I will create a community wiki answer with the list of the unknown contributors.  Please add the names beside each identifier.

Comment: Are the actual SCCS logs available somewhere?

Comment: Have you asked at the BSD fora? Perhaps old mailing lists contain full names + logins? In any case, any further information on the login could be helpful: Area of activity, rough timeframe, ...

Comment: @tripleee The logs are available on the CDs http://www.mckusick.com/csrg/.

Comment: @nonbrand You mean Free/Net/OpenBSD, right?  Good suggestion.  I can extract more data, but I'd hope someone has saved that time's map so as to avoid doing manual searches.

Comment: Just make sure to save/publish your results in some searchable format, i.e. give alias, name, and pointers to supporting evidence. Perhaps have several entries for an alias until it gets sorted out? There might also very well be several people using the same common username...

Comment: By intersecting these names with "ucbvax" I was able to fill in a bunch of them. However I should note that I have no first-hand knowledge on the matter.

Comment: I think Jeremy Reed is working on a book about early UNIX history- he's at reedmedia.net. It may be worth asking him for details.

Comment: I guess http://www.dmst.aueb.gr/dds/pubs/conf/2015-MSR-Unix-History/html/Spi15c.html is where this ended up?

Comment: Indeed!  Also today Warner Losh pointed me to a list of FreeBSD alumni names and login identifiers: https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/contributors/contrib-develalumni.html

Answer (score 3):

ah
aki
akito - Akito Fujita
andrew - [Andrew R. Cherenson](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news020f1/b35/fa/info-vax/00000880.html) ? (probably not [Andrew Palfreyman](http://files.chatnfiles.com/SPACE_Astronomy_1093/TEXT/SPACEDIG/V10_2/V10_210.TXT))
aoki - [Paul M. Aoki](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/termcap/termcap.src?view=co&revision=67590&content-type=text%2Fplain&pathrev=67590)
bill
borman - (probably not [Paul Borman](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg?view=revision&revision=66250)
bugs
bush
carl - [Carl Smith](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news006f1/b15/net/unix-wizards/00003106.html) (apparently not [Carl Lydick](http://cd.textfiles.com/spaceandast/TEXT/SPACEDIG/V13_6/V13_692.TXT))
cda
claudio
craig - [Craig Stanfill](http://fox.cs.vt.edu/VAD1/DOWN/AILIST/V4/092_127)
csvaf
csvsj
dab - [David Borman](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sys/netinet/tcp_fsm.h?rev=1.9&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)
denise
dist
dpk - (probably not [Doug Kingston](http://securitydigest.org/tcp-ip/archive/1984/10))
earl - [Earl Cohen](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/net.jokes.q/TtN8OopTi0w)
ecc - [Eric Cooper](http://quux.org:70/Archives/usenet-a-news/FA.works/81.10.29_ucbvax.4777_fa.works.txt)
edward - [Edward Wang](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!msg/comp.arch/B8Q7CDCURXY/LR8LQecZF3kJ) (not [Edward Hirgelt](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news135f1/b203/comp/sys/sun/00013546.html))
elefunt
epg
erics
evan - [Evan Kirshenbaum (??)](http://alt.usage.english.narkive.com/kF6d2At4/jesus-christ-what-s-going-on.3)
feldman - [Steven M. Feldman](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1062)
fitz
fortran
garrison
gray - [Bob Gray](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news001f1/a4/ucbvax.1849.html)
gusella - [Riccardo Gusella (?)](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1985/5512.html)
halbert - [Dan Halbert](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news011f1/b24/net/video/00000396.html)
harrison - [Michael A. Harrison](http://diswww.mit.edu/bloom-picayune.mit.edu/tex/465) (not [Peter Harrison](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news023f1/b41/net/micro/apple/00001754.html))
helge - [Helge Skrivervik](http://www.megalextoria.com/forum2/index.php?t=tree&goto=12194&)
henry - [Henry Spencer](http://yarchive.net/comp/array_bounds_check.html)
jaap - [Jaap Akkerhuis](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/X11/AUIS/ia-archive/apr.91.ascii)
jak
jas - [Jim Shankland](http://macgui.com/usenet/?group=14&id=24860)
jerry
jg
johnh - (probably not [John Doc Hayward](http://fox.cs.vt.edu/VAD1/AITOPIC/AILIST/V5255282))
kas
kurt - [Kurt Zeilenga](http://www-mice.cs.ucl.ac.uk/multimedia/misc/tcp_ip/8813.mm.www/0213.html)
lam
layer - [Kevin Layer](http://fox.cs.vt.edu/VAD1/DOWN/AILIST/V8/N008)
libs
mao
marc - [Marc Teitelbaum](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news096f1/b119/comp/unix/wizards/00015072.html) (not [Marc Kwiatkowski](http://massis.lcs.mit.edu/archives/back.issues/1990.volume.10/vol10.iss651-700) or [Marc Tarpennig](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news020f2/b36/net/games/trivia/00001327.html))
mark - [Mark R. Horton (mark@ucbvax)](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc976.pdf)
mis
mkm
mo - [Mike O'Dell](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news006f1/b15/net/bugs/4bsd/00000220.html)
opcode
orange - [Carol Orange](http://www.lysator.liu.se/etexts/recept/us/cheesecake-3.html)
pc
phil - [Phil Lapsley](http://stuff.mit.edu:8001/afs/sipb/project/beacon-src/sendmail/sendmail.5.61/cf/README)
presott
pugs
rick - [Rick Ellis](http://www.islandone.org/SpaceDigest/SpaceDigestArchive/RecentAcquisitions-SpaceDigest.v8-v17/v14no109)
rt
sagersa - [Alexander Sagers](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp//mail-archives/browse.cgi?p=djgpp/1992/02/24/18:30:21)
samples
sechrest - [Stuart Sechrest (?)](http://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/psd/20.ipctut/paper.pdf)
serge - [Serge Granik](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news048f1/b68/comp/lang/c++/00000012.html)
shantz
tapers
thien
trent
tut - [Bill Tuthill](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news006f1/b15/net/wanted/00001042.html)
wall - [Steve Wall](http://www.megalextoria.com/usenet-archive/news017f1/b30/net/games/rogue/00001991.html)
walsh
william - [Bill Jolitz](http://umcc.ais.org/%7Eronda/new.papers/usenet_early_days.txt)

Comment: I have speculations for a few but I was hardly born at the time. I would propose to post a separate answer with references rather than to edit this one. Can you provide a reference for the one name you offer, `akito`?

Comment: Sure, go ahead!  Akito comes from Jonathan Gray's list. I put the name there are an example of how we should complete the list.

Comment: Random googling suggests David Presotto, David Borman, maybe Nelson Beebe or K C Ng for `elefunt`.

Comment: Rev 3 thru 12 are from googling for `"ucbvax!foo"` and then I found a few more with `"ucbernie!foo"`. [UUCP bang paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUCP#UUCP_for_mail_routing) are tricky. Note in particular that while `ucbvax!foo` is a match, `ucbvax!foo@site` is not (necessarily); it could mean that a message from `foo@site` was archived by someone at UCB.

Comment: Clever idea!  Please contact me via email dds@aueb.gr.

Comment: By intersecting these names with "ucbvax" I was able to fill in a bunch of them. However I should note that I have no first-hand knowledge on the matter. / deleted by Michael Mrozek Feb 9 at 19:54 / answered Feb 9 at 14:16 / ruief / 1925 / Good idea, thanks for the tip! (Flagged as "not an answer" though.) tripleee Feb 9 at 15:34